# How to keep the code compact in the following case?

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, compile

Consider the following code:

```
TableVals = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^6, 2}];
cond1 = Hold@
   Compile[{{TableVals, _Real, 2}, {i, _Integer}}, 
    Boole[TableVals[[i]][[1]]^2 > 0.5]*
     Boole[0.7 > TableVals[[i]][[2]]], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] // ReleaseHold
BlockPars[parameter_] := Block[{},
  cond2 = 
   If[parameter > 1, 
    Hold@Compile[{{TableVals, _Real, 2}, {i, _Integer}}, 
       Boole[TableVals[[i]][[1]]*TableVals[[i]][[2]] > 0.2], 
       CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] // 
     ReleaseHold, 
    Hold@Compile[{{TableVals, _Real, 2}, {i, _Integer}}, 1, 
       CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] // 
     ReleaseHold];
  Summ = Hold@
       Compile[{{TableVals, _Real, 2}}, 
        Sum[cond1[TableVals, i]*cond2[TableVals, i], {i, 1, 
          Length[TableVals], 1}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. DownValues@cond1 /. 
     DownValues@cond2 // ReleaseHold;
  Summ[TableVals]
  ]
```

Its purpose is to evaluate some sum `Summ` with each term being the product of two conditions `cond1`, `cond2`. The second condition is controlled by some parameter `parameter`. If the latter is < 1, then `cond2` is just identity.

To compile `Summ`, I defined `cond2` in a very stupid way. Namely, if `parameter` < 1, I define its value ($\equiv 1$) via compiled function. This would decrease the performance of the evaluation compared to just the sum evaluation without `cond2`:

```
BlockPars[0.7] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {1.91724, 204667}

```
Summ2 = Hold@
     Compile[{{TableVals, _Real, 2}}, 
      Sum[cond1[TableVals, i], {i, 1, Length[TableVals], 1}], 
      CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. 
    DownValues@cond1 // ReleaseHold;
Summ2[TableVals] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.0203522, 204667}

The alternative to the definition of `Summ` in `Block` would be just to use `If`, not including `cond2` if `parameter`< 1:

```
Summ = If[parameter>1,Hold@
       Compile[{{TableVals, _Real, 2}}, 
        Sum[cond1[TableVals, i]*cond2[TableVals, i], {i, 1, 
          Length[TableVals], 1}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. DownValues@cond1 /. 
     DownValues@cond2 // ReleaseHold, Compile[{{TableVals, _Real, 2}}, 
        Sum[cond1[TableVals, i], {i, 1, 
          Length[TableVals], 1}], CompilationTarget -> "C", 
        RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"] /. DownValues@cond1 /. 
     DownValues@cond2 // ReleaseHold];
```

However, in my real situation this `If` would multiply the code length too significantly (as it just doubles the code length), and I would like to preserve a more compact way of defining `Summ` (like in the block above).

Could you please tell me how to preserve the compactness of the code while keep using `Compile` in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend to leave all the fluff away and to simply write two loops with a single branching to decide which loop to evaluate. Moreover, it might be a good idea to use boolean arithmetic (i.e. `&&`) instead of integer multiplication for the simple reason that the former allows for short circuiting. However, `sum += Boole[...]` seems to be faster than `If[..., ++sum];`, probably for the reason that this can go without branching.

```
cf = With[{c = Sqrt[0.5]},

  Compile[{{TableVals, _Real, 2}, {parameter, _Real}},
    Block[{n, sum, a, b},
     
     n = Length[TableVals];
     sum = 0;
     
     If[parameter > 1.,
      
      Do[
       a = Compile`GetElement[TableVals, i, 1];
       b = Compile`GetElement[TableVals, i, 2];
       sum += Boole[(0.7 > b) && (Abs[a] > c ) && (a b > 0.2)];
       , {i, 1, n}
       ]
      ,
      Do[
        a = Compile`GetElement[TableVals, i, 1];
        b = Compile`GetElement[TableVals, i, 2];
        sum += Boole[(0.7 > b) && (Abs[a] > c )];
        , {i, 1, n}
        ];
      ];
     sum
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ];
```

Not only does this convey the *intent* more clearly to your fellow developers; it is also 100 times faster in execution. Probably because it compiles a function only once -- and not for every single call to `BlockPars`.

Actually `` CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint[Summ] `` reveals this:

```
        1 argument
        11 Integer registers
        1 Tensor register
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking off
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        T(R2)0 = A1
        I5 = 0
        I0 = 1
        Result = I3

1   I3 = I5
2   I6 = Length[ T(R2)0]
3   I9 = I5
4   goto 10
5   I7 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[cond1][ T(R2)0, I9]]
6   I10 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[cond2][ T(R2)0, I9]]
7   I7 = I7 * I10
8   I10 = I3 + I7
9   I3 = I10
10  if[ ++ I9 <= I6] goto 5
11  Return
```

As you can see, `cond1` and `cond2` have *not* been inlined, defeating the whole purpose of compilation.

If you really want to preevaluate some bits of code at compile time, you can do it like this:

```
ClearAll[cg]
cg[boolean : True | False] := cg[boolean] = Block[{a, b, c},
    
    c = Sqrt[0.5];
    
    With[{
      code = Boole[(0.7 > b) && (Abs[a] > c ) && (boolean || a b > 0.2)]
      },
     
     Compile[{{TableVals, _Real, 2}},
      Block[{n, sum, a, b},
       
       n = Length[TableVals];
       sum = 0;
       
       Do[
        a = Compile`GetElement[TableVals, i, 1];
        b = Compile`GetElement[TableVals, i, 2];
        sum += code
        , {i, 1, n}
        ];

       sum

       ],
      CompilationTarget -> "C",
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ]
     ]
    ];
```

You then would call it like this:

```
ch[0.7 > 1.][TableVals]
```

`ch` uses memoization to lazily compile a function only for two cases: `boolean == True` and `boolean == False`. "Lazily" because `ch` will invoke only compilation for one of the values when it is really called. I let *Mathematica* simplify the logical expression in `code` and inline the simplified result with `With`. (I was a bit disappointed that the compiler was not able to simplify the expression `Boole[(0.7 > b) && (Abs[a] > c ) && (boolean || a b > 0.2)]` although `boolean` is a compile-time constant...)